# ssrs 2008 help - blank managment page

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have installed SQLSERVER2k8r2 (with ssrs) on a win 7pro virtual machine, but every time i try to go to the report manager page though IE , firefox, chrome , all i get is only a blank page no header bar or anything just a blank page.

Every time i try it by running as admin in IE, have set http://Win7VM as a trusted site, i get no error codes or messages like access denied, turned off the windows firewall cause this is a test VM have no anti-virus installed on it.

I have been on google for the last whole day trying to find out why this is happening , have not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I haven't had this issue but I have heard of others having it and it was due to some permissions issue.

Check out to see if it helps:

http://dobrzanski.net/2008/03/28/reporting-services-blank-report-manager-screen/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/fffa4d0d-6cc9-4385-8a30-8a1b8243f619/report-manager-blank-page